# Estou com problemas no meu sistema de login

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php
include('conexao.php');

if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['senha'])) {
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit();
}


$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['senha']);

$query = 'select usuario_id, usuario from usuario where usuario = '{$usuario}' and senha = md5('{$senha}')';

$result =  mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

$row = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($row == 1) {
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    header('Location: home.html');
    exit();
} else {
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit();
}
```

Ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' and senha = md5('' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 13

Por favor me ajudem eu não faço ideia do quê possa ser ...

Comment: Quando usar variáveis dentro de um string utilize strings com aspas duplas. Enfim, na linha que está o seu erro substitua o primeiro e o último ' por ".

Comment: Mas para fazer um consulta ao banco de dados, ainda mais em uma área tão sensível quanto o login, por favor utilize no mínimo mysqly::prepare().

Comment: Também não se deve usar o md5 para "criptografar" senhas

Answer (score 1):

Eu recomendo usar **PrepareStatement** por questões de segurança e para evitar riscos maiores de SQLInjection, eu simulei uma sessão pegando o perfil de acesso do usuário, e a id dele, porque é só isso basicamente que vc precisaria, em tese, numa sessão:

```
if (!$_POST || empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['senha'])) {
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit();
}

$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
$senha = MD5($_POST['senha']);

$query = "SELECT id, role FROM usuario WHERE usuario = ? AND senha = ?";

 if (!($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexao, $query) && $usuario && $senha)) {
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit();
 } else {
    $setParams = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $usuario, $senha);
    $execute = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $results = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    $array_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

    //print_r($array_result);

   if (!$results) {
        header('Location: index.html');
        exit();
    }

    if (!isset($array_result['id'])) {
        header('Location: index.html');
        exit();
    }

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $array_result['id'];
    $_SESSION['nivel_acesso'] = $array_result['role'];
    header('Location: home.html');
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

***Olá @JeanExtreme002, tudo bem?***
Atualizei o $_POST atribuído na variável "**senha**" e atualizei a sua query.
Altere o seu código para tal:

```
<?php
include('conexao.php');

if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['senha'])) {
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit();
}


$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, md5($_POST['senha']));

$query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha'";

$result =  mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

$row = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($row == 1) {
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    header('Location: home.html');
    exit();
} else {
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit();
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.
Cumprimentos,
***minds'***.

Comment: Então @minds, da forma que você fez, se eu passar o parâmetro  `' or 1 = 1 or 1 = '` no campo, eu entro no sistema. Porque a query ficaria: `SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario = '' or 1 = 1 or 1 = '' AND senha = 'qualquercoisa'`

Comment: O nome do autor da pergunta é Pedro Henrrique. O Jean foi quem fez a edição melhorando o texto.

Comment: @IvanFerrer Mas ele tá usando a função mysqli_real_escape_string() para os campos usuario e senha.

Comment: Eu sei @Andre, mas `mysqli_real_escape_string`, só escapa aspas, não evita inserção de dados, é meio arriscado não acha., por exemplo isso não te protege de: `5 OR 1=1`

Comment: @IvanFerrer Entendi Ivan... Perguntei só por curiosidade mesmo... Obrgiado pelos esclarecimentos!

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao SOpt @minds, veja acima o comentário de  Augusto Vasques.